# How to install MongoDB after downloading

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

**Task:**
To install MongoDB after downloading

**To Note:**
I can't install it from terminal for some reasons. And I am using Ubuntu 14.04

I just don't know what to do after downloading. Coz there are no executable files or something.

Comment: Extract the file somewhere, and append the bin directory to your env variable PATH.

Comment: @Yuan can you please explain this step by step, like you would explain to a complete beginner

Comment: The MongoDB manual has a tutorial for how to [Install MongoDB on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: @Stennie, please note that in the question, I said I cannot install it from terminal (that's how it is done in the manual) for some reasons. I had to download it

Comment: @Joe: Was there a specific error you were getting when trying to install via terminal? There is also a tutorial for [installing on Linux](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/) if you can't use the packages for some reason. Installing the Ubuntu package is better as you get a service definition and can upgrade via the normal package manager (apt/Synaptic).

Comment: @Stennie, that link you gave was really helpful, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is preety good article for installation of mongodb step by step.

[How-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

[Click here for mongoDB tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-mongodb-tutorials/)

To start your mongodb server : `mongod`

You may find error that database directory is not created. For that,

Create your database directory(default path) : `mkdir -p /data/db` and then restart your server again.If you did not find any error then skip this part.You can also change your database directory path. Here is command for that `mongod --dbpath /your/path`

[image]

Open new terminal and execute : `mongo`

[image]

If you have any query feel free to comment.Good luck.

Comment: after creating the database directory, I extract the files there right? is that all? can I start my mongodb server?

Comment: The problem is that mongodb is not installed yet. I just have the zip file. Where do I extract those files in zip file? and then what?

Comment: If you have portable version then extract it any where you are comfortable and go to bin directory where you can find mongodb commands .Export this directory path to run mongodb command anywhere you want and follow above intstruction to start mongo.