# Upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 from 14.10 breaks mongo - how to fix?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I made the mistake yesterday of upgrading to 15.04 :-).  Now my mongod can't start:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
connecting to: test
2015-04-26T08:45:08.339-0600 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-04-26T08:45:08.339-0600 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

sudo service mongod status

```
● mongod.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

So next, I searched for the lock file related to mongodb and removed it.
- no help.
So next I did:

```
sudo -u mongodb mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/
sudo service mongodb start

 sudo -u mongodb mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/
2015-04-26T08:56:39.844-0600 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=17760 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb/ 64-bit host=Parke.dynu.com
2015-04-26T08:56:39.844-0600 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.9
2015-04-26T08:56:39.844-0600 [initandlisten] git version: df313bc75aa94d192330cb92756fc486ea604e64
2015-04-26T08:56:39.844-0600 [initandlisten] build info: Linux build20.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-04-26T08:56:39.844-0600 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-04-26T08:56:39.844-0600 [initandlisten] options: { repair: true, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb/" } }
2015-04-26T08:56:39.860-0600 [initandlisten] repairDatabase tracker
2015-04-26T08:56:39.860-0600 [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/tracker.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:39.906-0600 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/tracker.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:39.907-0600 [FileAllocator] creating directory /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
2015-04-26T08:56:39.908-0600 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/tracker.0, size: 64MB,  took 0 secs
2015-04-26T08:56:39.942-0600 [initandlisten] repairDatabase tracker-test
2015-04-26T08:56:39.942-0600 [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/tracker-test.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:39.987-0600 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/tracker-test.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:39.988-0600 [FileAllocator] creating directory /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
2015-04-26T08:56:39.990-0600 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/tracker-test.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.001 secs
2015-04-26T08:56:40.020-0600 [initandlisten] repairDatabase test
2015-04-26T08:56:40.020-0600 [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/test.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.065-0600 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/test.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.065-0600 [FileAllocator] creating directory /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
2015-04-26T08:56:40.067-0600 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/test.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.001 secs
2015-04-26T08:56:40.078-0600 [initandlisten] repairDatabase admin
2015-04-26T08:56:40.078-0600 [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/admin.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.123-0600 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/admin.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.123-0600 [FileAllocator] creating directory /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
2015-04-26T08:56:40.125-0600 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/admin.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.001 secs
2015-04-26T08:56:40.148-0600 [initandlisten] repairDatabase tracker-dev
2015-04-26T08:56:40.148-0600 [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/tracker-dev.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.195-0600 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/tracker-dev.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.195-0600 [FileAllocator] creating directory /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
2015-04-26T08:56:40.197-0600 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/tracker-dev.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.001 secs
2015-04-26T08:56:40.238-0600 [initandlisten] repairDatabase local
2015-04-26T08:56:40.238-0600 [initandlisten] allocating new ns file /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/local.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.285-0600 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/local.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.285-0600 [FileAllocator] creating directory /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
2015-04-26T08:56:40.288-0600 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/local.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.001 secs
2015-04-26T08:56:40.300-0600 [initandlisten] finished checking dbs
2015-04-26T08:56:40.300-0600 [initandlisten] dbexit: 
2015-04-26T08:56:40.300-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.300-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.300-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.300-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.300-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.300-0600 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-04-26T08:56:40.300-0600 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-04-26T08:56:40.300-0600 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
joel@Parke:/var/lib/mongodb$ sudo service mongodb start
Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

Still no help.  So next I created a /data/db directory in the hopes that this might work -- no go....
So any ideas? I assume this is related to the move away from upstart?

Thanks...

Comment: the /etc/init.d/mongod is a symlink to /lib/init/upstart-job so I think that your guess that this is related to upstart is probably correct.

Comment: I managed to get mongo to run, but not entirely sure what solved it yet. I was messing around with varios things I found here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7285

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For others that run across this - what a pain!
It turns out that Mongo>2.6.3 has a known issue with start: Support Systemd (cannot start mongodb with init scripts with Fedora 15 or above)
As noted here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17742 and it seems that this possibly won't be fully fixed for >2.6.3 until Ubuntu 16.04, unless there is a strong outcry.

So the solution for me was to issue:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mongodb
```

This reverted back to mongo 2.6.3 and NOW ALL WORKS!
For those that run across this... 
Thanks to all who looked at this!

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! You just saved me a lot of time and headache.

Comment: Certainly - glad it helped... stack overflow is a life saver!

Comment: For those who don't understand from first attempt like me: this will drop mongodb-org which is fresh, shiny and _broken_ on 15.04, and install 2.6.3 from Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Is this still the best advice available. Mongolab are upgrading all of their systems to Mongo 3 and I wanted to upgrade on my ubuntu development machine to be sure nothing was going to break. I'm not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 10):

A [comment here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17742?focusedCommentId=898346&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-898346) (in the Jira ticket referenced by @JoelParke) explains how to cleanly install current versions of mongodb (> 3.0) on Ubuntu 15.04 by replacing the apt source:

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

Be aware that Mongoid 4 can't authenticate to Mongo 3. This will be fixed in Mongoid 5.

Comment: Best !! Ubuntu 15.0 users try this #WorksCharm

Answer (score 3):

You can use the debian package instead, follow the instructions (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/) and replace the source with

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian wheezy/mongodb-org/3.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list

Answer (score 2):

## Start mongod as a Daemon in latest version (3.2)

To run a mongod process as a daemon, and write its output to a log file, use the `--fork` and `--logpath` options. You must create the log directory; however, mongod will create the log file if it does not exist.

The following command starts mongod as a daemon and records log output to `/var/log/mongodb.log`.

> mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log

**Additional Configuration Options**
For an overview of common configurations and deployments for common use cases, see Run-time Database Configuration.

## Stop mongod Processes

In a clean shutdown a mongod completes all pending operations, flushes all data to data files, and closes all data files. Other shutdowns are unclean and can compromise the validity of the data files.

To ensure a clean shutdown, always shutdown mongod instances using one of the following methods:

**Use shutdownServer()**

Shut down the mongod from the mongo shell using the `db.shutdownServer()` method as follows:

> use admin
>   db.shutdownServer()

Calling the same method from a init script accomplishes the same result.

For systems with authorization enabled, users may only issue db.shutdownServer() when authenticated to the admin database or via the localhost interface on systems without authentication enabled.

**Use --shutdown**

From the Linux command line, shut down the mongod using the `--shutdown` option in the following command:

> mongod --shutdown